# How do I translate JSON elements with googletrans in Python giving not NoneType error

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, google-translate

This program takes data from an API and translates one element to English then exports it to JSON together with other elements.

However I get this error message:

> the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType

```py
import requests
import json
import re
import unicodedata
from datetime import datetime
from googletrans import Translator

translator = Translator()

def get_requests_result(url, page_number):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url + str(page_number))
        res.raise_for_status()
        return res
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise Exception(f"Requesting page {page_number} failed: {e}")

def get_json_content(res):
    return res.json()['results']

def strip_html_tags(text):
    clean_text = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', text)
    return clean_text

def translate_unicode_characters(text):
    translated_text = ''.join(
        char if ord(char) < 128 else unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', char).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        for char in text
    )
    return translated_text

def translate_to_english(text):
    try:
        return translator.translate(text, dest='en').text
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error translating text: {e}")
        return text  # Return the original text if translation fails

def transform_job_listing(job, search, job_number):
    job_description = job.get("contents", "")
    translated_description = translate_to_english(job_description)
    
    transformed_job = {
        "job_number": job_number,
        "job_title": job.get("name", ""),
        "company_name": job.get("company", {}).get("name", ""),
        "job_location": job.get("locations", [{}])[0].get("name", "") if job.get("locations") else "",
        "search_keyword": job.get("categories", [{}])[0].get("name", "") if job.get("categories") else "",
        "job_level": job.get("levels", [{}])[0].get("name", "") if job.get("levels") else "",
        "publication_date": job.get("publication_date", ""),
        "job_url": job.get("refs", {}).get("landing_page", ""),
        "search_datetime": datetime.now().isoformat(),
        "search_location": search["location"],
        "job_description": translated_description
    }
    return transformed_job

search_keyword = "Data%20and%20Analytics"
url_themuse = f"https://www.themuse.com/api/public/jobs?category={search_keyword}&location=Berlin%2C%20Germany&page="

search = {
    "keyword": "Data and Analytics",
    "location": "Berlin, Germany"
}

file_number = 1
job_number = 1
filtered_jobs_buffer = []

for page_number in range(0, 50):
    try:
        res = get_requests_result(url_themuse, page_number)
        json_file = get_json_content(res)

        for job in json_file:
            job['contents'] = strip_html_tags(job['contents'])
            job['contents'] = translate_unicode_characters(job['contents'])
            transformed_job = transform_job_listing(job, search, job_number)

            if 'Berlin, Germany' in transformed_job.get('job_location', ''):
                transformed_job['job_number'] = job_number
                filtered_jobs_buffer.append(transformed_job)
                job_number += 1

            if len(filtered_jobs_buffer) == 20:
                json_filename = f"the_muse_jobs_{file_number}.json"
                with open(json_filename, 'w') as json_file:
                    json.dump(filtered_jobs_buffer, json_file, indent=4)
                print(f"Saved 20 jobs in '{json_filename}'.")
                filtered_jobs_buffer = []
                file_number += 1

    except Exception as exception:
        print(exception)
        break

if filtered_jobs_buffer:
    json_filename = f"the_muse_jobs_{file_number}.json"
    with open(json_filename, 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(filtered_jobs_buffer, json_file, indent=4)
    print(f"Saved the remaining {len(filtered_jobs_buffer)} jobs in '{json_filename}'.")
```

I want to translate the `job_description` element only.

I understand that it means that there is no data, but If I remove all the translation functionality, the code exports the JSON perfectly.

I have another program which scrapes from web and translates the same element and it works, but not this one taking the data from the API, which works without trying to translate it.